# GooglePlay отмена/отклонение платежа

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Вопрос на понимание.

Продаю несколько приложений через GP (как платные приложения, так и контент). С завидной долей регулярности в "Управлении заказами" вижу статус "Платеж отклонен" или "Отмененные". 
В доках написано, что это возможно из-за разных причин (например нехватка денег, некорректный оператор и т.п.). Но некоторые покупатели пытаются совершить покупку по нескольку (до 8!) раз в разное время и она всё равно не проходит. Думаю, что люди достаточно сообразительны, чтобы хотя бы со второго раза уже положить деньги :)

Поэтому возможно причина отмен в чем-то другом? Возможно надо как-то по другому настроить публикацию приложения, внести изменения в код и т.п.?

Или, и другие публикующиеся разработчики меня поддержат, это нормальное явление - примерно 30% отклоненных платежей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Честно я не знаю, но скажу вот что: сам контент в приложении никогда не покупал, но были случаи, когда случайно(и не только) нажимал на кнопочку покупки и отменял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Отмена платежа из-за добавочной стоимости. Сейчас во многих странах Google показывает цену без %налога. При оплате пользователь видит уже полную стоимость. У нас добавляется немного, в некоторых странах - весьма много. Это влияет на отказ
2. Отмена платежа по ошибке. Сюда я сгруппировал все подобные варианты. Не буду рассматривать их по отдельности.
3. Проблема прохождения транзакции. Как я понимаю, уже на уровне взаимодействия с банком. В некоторых случаях платёж не поступит несмотря на то, что пользователь получит программу. В некоторых случаях срабатывает родительский контроль, отменяющий оплату, произведенную ребенком и т.п.
4. Программы-взломщики а ля "Freedom". Эти самые "8 раз", как правило, обусловлены ими.

Возможно, есть ещё варианты.

P.S. 30% - это не так уж и много :) Хотя всё зависит от цены и тематики (читай: аудитории).

Comment: спасибо! +5 к пониманию ;)