# Проблемы с In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchases

Возникла странная проблема: в статистике по приложению больше 100 раз пытались купить In-App, но при этом каждая попытка заканчивалась ошибкой "Cannot connect to iTunes Store".
Нормальная ли это ситуация?

Сами лично тестили, все нормально покупается и работает. Так же опытным путем выяснили что такая ошибка возникает если у пользователя не указан метод оплаты или не хватает средств на счете.
Но как то странно если у 100% потенциальных покупателей проблемы с оплатой.

Comment: Скажите, вы решили данную проблему? Если да, можете поделиться решением?

Comment: @Alexander к сожалению нет.. сейчас переносим игру на Unity и будем использовать нативную систему IAP - если уже и с ней будут такие проблемы, значит ничего страшного. Ибо грешили больше всего на стороннюю библиотеку для IAP которую использовали, но если и от Unity так же будет, значит так и должно быть.

Comment: Какую стороннюю библиотеку использовали?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уже отвечал на похожий (но не подобный) вопрос: [GooglePlay отмена/отклонение платежа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649977/googleplay-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0/763733#763733). Считаю, что у вас наиболее вероятен пункт 4, а именно: использование/попытка использования программы-взломщика для In-App Purchase или одной из методик "бесплатной покупки в приложении".

Более подробно можно попытаться проанализировать, если знать возрастную направленность приложения (точнее, возрастную направленность контента, который должны были бы купить).