# В Google Play Console есть состояние платежа: Платеж отклонен. Что это такое?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

Кем отклонен?

За что отклонен?

Клиентом или Системой платежа или еще кем или чем? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Две наиболее распространенные причины, по которым Google "отклоняет" платежи:

1. У клиента недостаточно денег на счету.
2. Платежная система клиента не поддерживается Google.

Если клиент отменяет платеж по собственной инициативе, состояние называется "Платеж возвращен".

По опыту могу сказать, что нормальная ситуация, когда около 10-30% заказов отменяются.

[Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649977/googleplay-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0) мне отвечали на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо! Jarvis_J )

Comment: У меня этот процент более, чем в 2 раза выше. Очень странно...