# Платные push-уведомления Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-уведомления

Сабж.
Слышал, что Apple запрещает делать платным любой встроенный функционал. В частности, нельзя по подписке или как-то еще требовать с людей деньги за получение пуш-уведомлений.

Как с этим у Google? Можно ли за отдельную плату предоставлять такие услуги? Если гугл это не волнует, то нет ли у Firebase (как у непосредственно сервиса, предоставляющего услугу) таких ограничений?

UPD: конкретную информацию (хотя бы для сравнения) для iOS и Apple тоже не нашёл, так что информация и для этой платформы тоже приветствуется.

Comment: да, легко.............

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  не относится к программированию или системному администрированию

Comment: @Jarvis_J вопрос относится к правовому аспекту разработки под одну из платформ. Вопросы о выводе денег и других моментах чувствуют себя прекрасно в сообществе, да и [вы сами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649977/googleplay-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0) задаёте подобные вопросы. В чём проблема?

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, нет единого мнения по этому вопросу) раньше находились те, кто постоянно меня упрекал за защиту подобных вопросов. Но, тем не менее, вопросы удалялись с АНАЛОГИЧНОЙ формулировкой. Сейчас попробовал себя "на другой стороне". Хотелось бы единой логики сообщества и поведения модераторов. Но что-то других "борцов за чистоту ресурса" не видать. Не воспринимайте на свой счет лично, вы молодец, я бы тоже ответ на ваш вопрос почитал :)

Comment: @PeterSamokhin, многие вопросы о выводе денег не чувствуют себя прекрасно. Потому, что они, к сожалению, удалены :(